# Turn 120 volts two plug outside into AC connection

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

i have a question reguarding an AC hookup for my workshop. the workshop is on the other side of the house connected by the garage, and it gets to 95 deggrees. oof!  I am currently looking into purchasing a DIY MINI SPLIT 12000 BTU 120v [(Link to product here)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083YM3D2V) and i need to figure out how to properly wire the thing.

I'm pretty sure this outlet is on a circuit with other outlets in the workshop, so if that's a problem I need to know. My breaker appears to be full up so routing another wire may not be an option.

so my question is, is it possible to turn this outside outlet into the necessary wiring connections to hook up the aforementioned AC unit?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check with the vendor/manufacturer to see if the unit needs a dedicated circuit.

Comment: Would you be plugging it in on the outside of the house? Would you be removing the outlet and hardwiring something into the box? Would you need to gain access to the wires on the inside of the house and close off access from the outside?

Comment: Can you post photos of your breaker panel please?

Comment: as requested i uploaded a picture of whats on my circuit breaker. i would be plugging the condenser side on the outside of the house, removing the outlet and using it as a dedicated connector. im not sure if the whole outside of the house is connected on one circuit. there are multiple outlets around the exterior of the house, so im going to check on whether they are all connected on 29.

Comment: the outlet in question is in 29. all of the patio outlets

Comment: Can you post a photo showing the breakers in your panel please?

Comment: @Daniel It looks like you created a second account. See [this Help Center page](/help/merging-accounts) for how to fix that

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

For the 12000 btu unit you linked to it is 120v.
Are there any other loads on this outlet or circuit?
A 12000 btu unit normally draws under 15 amps with an inverter.
The one main concern I know about on these units are using a sealant like nylog blue to make sure the fittings do not leak. We had a class over a year ago they mentioned servicing these units the number 1 problem was leaking fittings.
I have not used one but would use nylog blue . No interest in the company I use the product.
As far as tapping that receptacle if nothing else is on that line I would feed a disconnect from the receptacle and use it that way.

As with all splits make sure to hang the unit level or slightly lower on the drain side. Do not kink the drain and cut the line off just above the ground.

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, "it depends". Code requires one outlet on the front of the house and one on the back as a minimum.   I also believe outdoor outlets need to be on their own circuit these days. soooo, probably not code legal to do so. Also, since it's a permanently attached appliance, if it's current draw is over 50% of the amperage of the circuit, it can't share with outlets.